# How to access JavaScript function which is in function which is in function

Tags: javascript, function, this

Is there any way to access a function which is inside a function, which is inside an other function in JavaScript?

```js
function x(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;


  this.a = function() {
    this.b = function() {
      return "b";
    };

    return "a";
  };
}

var xobj = new x('vin', 25);
console.log(xobj.a.b()); //error
```

Comment: What is your use case? To me this seems unclear, why would one ever need this? Declare the function at the top level and don't bother with nesting unless there's absolutely no way around this terribad (no offense) pattern. I think you're not explaining your _problem_ but rather, the _problem of your solution_. Maybe if we know the idea behind this, we can give you a better alternative instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```js
function x(name, age){
 this.name  =name;
 this.age = age;
 

 this.a = function(){
   
  this.b = function(){
   return "b";
        };

 return "a";
  };
  
}


var xobj =new x('vin',25);
var xx = new xobj.a();
console.log(xx.b());
```

you would have to declare an instance of x.a() and then call b

When a function is used as a constructor (with the new keyword), its this is bound to the new object being constructed. so If you want to call this inside the function a(), you would have to create a constructor using [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-different than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: `xobj.a()` returns a string `"a"`

Comment: no it won't, it would return an instance of this because of the **new** operator

Comment: While it would work, this way of coding isn't going to help anyone (including **future you**) reading your code. It doesn't make it clearer or cleaner but rather messier and more complex than it should be. Of course, I cannot be sure about that because full context isn't given in the question. Thumbs up for "providing a way" at least :)

Comment: as well as am eager to know, whether its an good practice and  whether this scenario is implemented in default objects of javascript

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to avoid this situation as well as avoid using [@marvel308's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584978/2224331). I don't dislike the user of course :) I just dislike the readability and understandability that the linked answer provides despite good effort. While it may be a solution, it is one you'll probably have to google every time you see it used since it isn't easy to understand -- lets avoid that.

Depending on what you want, there are multiple alternatives, you could rethink the structure of your program to be more "flat" for instance.
Nesting usually makes things more complex so avoiding it will do you good most of the time.

Now if **nesting isn't** something that is **absolutely required**, you could opt for this, much simpler solution instead, using multiple functions defined at the top level:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}

function sayHelloToPerson(person) {
    console.log("Hello! " + person.name + ", it seems you are: " + person.age + " years old");
}
```

In action:

```
var me = new Person("SidOfc", 22);
sayHelloToPerson(me);
// => "Hello! SidOfc, it seems you are: 22 years old"
```

I cannot be sure about the usability of this code since the use case is too unclear but in this way, you keep the intention clear and you can always use function arguments to pass in any data your function needs (like `person` argument in this case.).

If you, like every other JS developer out there hates polluting the global namespace, wrap all functions related to `x` (`Person` in my example) **directly** inside it instead of nesting deeper than 1 level. e.g.

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;

    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello! " + this.name + ", it seems you are: " + this.age + " years old");
        this.sayGoodbye();
    };

    this.sayGoodbye = function() {
        console.log("Goodbye! " + this.name);
    }
}
```

In action:

```
var me2 = new Person("SidOfc", 22);
me2.sayHello();
// => "Hello! SidOfc, it seems you are: 22 years old"
// since sayHello calls this.sayGoodbye() we also get:
// => "Goodbye! SidOfc"
```

The idea behind this is that you create all functions that are related to your `x` (`Person` in my example) at the same level of nesting.

They can then call other functions **and** properties within the instance easily without these crazy nesting structures. No parameters have to be added either since you're calling the function from *that* instance (of course, that will change depending on your needs).

As an added bonus, you don't need what you're asking for anymore since you can now just access the function using `me2.somefunction()` instead of having to dig deep.

Hope I could be of assistance ;)