# How to access a function in a function with `this`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584951/how-to-access-javascript-function-which-is-in-function-which-is-in-function).

However, mine runs in Node.js and it seems like a bit more complicated.

The server side wasn't built by me, but someone else that I can't contact. And he wrote code very differently.

And I have `db.js` and it looks like this:

[image]

And `routes/email.js` it uses `db.js` like this:

[image]

And when I click a button. I get this error:

```
db.emailRequest is not a function
```

in `db.js`, at the end of the file. It originally had this:

```
module.exports = new dbHelper;
```

And my style to use `db.js` in routers.

```
db.get().query(sql, input, function(err,res){
    //TODO:
});
```

But it didn't work. So, I changed the end of `db.js` like this:

```
exports.get = function(){
        console.log("exports.get");
        return pool;
}
```

And also added some code in `app.js` like this:

```
db.connect(function(err){
   if(err){
      console.log('Unable to connect to MariaDB');
      process.exit(1);
   }
});
```

What should I do?

The full code of `db.js` is here:

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

var pool;

exports.connect = function(done){
        console.log("Trying to connect DB...");
        pool = mariadb.createPool({
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'xxxxxxx',
                database:"XXXXX",
                connectionLimit: 5 // Why 5 ???
        });

        pool.getConnection()
                .then(conn => {
                console.log("DB connected. id: " + conn.threadId);
                conn.end(); //release to pool
        }).catch(err => {
                console.log("DB failed connection: " + err);
        });

}

function makeToken(){
        console.log("makeToken()");
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
  for(var i=0;i<32;i++){
      text+=possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

function dbHelper() {
        console.log("dbHelper()");
  this.emailRequest = function(email,num){
        console.log("emailRequest");
    pool.getConnection().then(conn => {
      conn.query("INSERT INTO email_verification(email, code) VALUES(?,?)",[email,num]);
      conn.end(); //release to pool
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("not connected due to error: " + err);
    });
  }

  // wait and process until getting return value because rv is needed.
  this.verify = async function(email,num){
        console.log("verify");
    let conn;
    var result = false;
    try {
      conn = await pool.getConnection();
      // within 3minutes
      const rows = await conn.query("SELECT count(*) FROM email_verificaiton WHERE email=? AND code=? AND req_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE",[email,num]);
      if(rows[0]["count(*)"]>0){
        result = true;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    } finally {
      if (conn) conn.end();
    }
      return result;
  }

  this.verifyUpdate = function(email,num){
        console.log("verifyUpdate");
    pool.getConnection()
    .then(conn => {
      conn.query("UPDATE email_verification SET status = 1 WHERE email=? AND code=?",[email,num]);
      conn.end(); //release to pool
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("not connected due to error: " + err);
    });
  }

  // wait and process until getting return value because rv is needed.
  this.emailRegister = async function(email,pass,nick,devid){
        console.log("emailRegister");
    let conn;
    var result;
    try {
      conn = await pool.getConnection();
      var rows = await conn.query("SELECT count(*) FROM email_verification WHERE email=? AND status = 1",[email]);
      if(rows[0]["count(*)"]>0){
        rows = await conn.query("SELECT count(*) FROM member WHERE email=?",[email]);
        if(rows[0]["count(*)"]==0){
          var token = makeToken();
          rows = await conn.query("INSERT INTO member (email,password,username,device_id,login_method,token) VALUES(?,?,?,?,0,?)",[email,pass,nick,devid,token]);
          if(rows["affectedRows"]>0){
            result = {result:true, code:200, message: "success",data:[{email:email,token:token}]};
          } else{
            result = {result:false,code:401, message:"db error"};
          }

        }else {
          result = {result:false,code:402, message:"already registered id"};
        }
      } else {
        result = {result:false,code:403, meesage:"email not verified"};
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    } finally {
      if (conn) conn.end();
    }
    return result;
  }
  // wait and process until getting return value because rv is needed.
  this.emailLogin = async function(email,pass,devid){
        console.log("emailLogin");
    let conn;
    var result;
    try {
      conn = await pool.getConnection();
      rows = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE email=?",[email]);
      if(rows.length==1){
        if(rows[0]["password"]==pass){
          var token = makeToken();
          rows = await conn.query("UPDATE member SET device_id = ?, token = ? WHERE email=?",[devid,token,email]);
          console.log(rows)
          if(rows["affectedRows"]>0){
            result = {result:true,message:"Sign up Success.", code:200, data:[{email:email,token:token}]};
          } else{
            result = {result:false,message:"db error",code:401};
          }
        } else {
          result = {result:false,message:"wrong password",code:402};
        }
      }else {
        result = {result:false,message:"not registered id",code:403};
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    } finally {
      if (conn) conn.end();
    }
    return result;
  }
}

//module.exports = new dbHelper;

exports.get = function(){
        console.log("exports.get");
        return pool;
}
```

Comment: Why `this.emailRequest` is not an `async` function? Is that `pool.getConnection()` a Promise?

Comment: I am sorry... I didn't write the code and there is no comment, So, I am not sure his purpose of those. But, I changed it to `this.emailRequest = async function...` and it shows the same error. And `pool.getConnection()` immediately shows message as soon as the server runs.

Comment: If you never export `dbHelper` how do you anticipate being able to access any of its methods/properties? As a band-aid, try putting a property on `pool`: `pool.dbHelper = new dbHelper();` inside your exported `get` routine. Then you could reference `db.get().dbHelper.emailRequest(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much!, I solved the problem. @Forty3. And I have one more question, is `poo.getConnection()` part badly implemented in `db.js`?

Comment: I cannot say whether or not `pool.getConnection()` is poorly implemented without knowing what else is going into the `.connect(...)` method. As it looks, as soon as it gets the connection it ends it, so...